# shadow password

Tags: php, linux, authentication

I'm trying to compare shadow password with php cli but not work ! i use this function so i can create password like shadow

```
function shadow ($input){
    for ($n = 0; $n < 9; $n++){
        $s .= chr(rand(64,126));
    }
    $seed =  "$1$".$s."$";
    $return = crypt($input,$seed);
    return $return;
}
```

when i replace the result in shadow it's work with the password but it's have different character how i can compare it .

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your function creates a *random* salt (variable `seed`) using the php `rand` function. Thus, your salt will be different than the salt used by the existing password in the shadow file.

If you want to *compare* hashes (i.e. compare the output of your `crypt` call with the value in `shadow`), both hashes need to be created with the *same* salt. Thus, you need to use the salt from the existing password in the shadow file (= the `$1$...$` part) instead of creating your own randomly.

In other words, drop your function and just use `crypt($input, '$1$...$')` instead, with `$1$...$` being the first part of the hash in `/etc/shadow`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the salt stored in the password file:

```
 $crypted=crypt($_POST['password'], $stored_password);
 if ($crypted==$stored_password) ( // they match
```

Note that you don't have to explicity extract the salt from the stored password, nor worry about the algorithm/salt size - crypt does that for you.

C.

Answer (score 0):

It might also be worth looking into the [PAM pecl extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/PAM) instead of fiddling with /etc/shadow.

> This extension provides PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) integration. PAM is a system of libraries that handle the authentication tasks of applications and services. The library provides a stable API for applications to defer to for authentication tasks.